# Finding values in a convergent geometric series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}$ denote a convergent geometric series with $a_0 = 1$ and sum to infinity equals to $1521$. Find the value of $\ln(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n})$. Give your answer corrected to two decimal places.

May I ask how I can go about solving this? I really don't know how to work with the ln() function there. Thanks!

Comment: What does $\frac{1}{1-x}$ equal?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a geometric series, we may write $a_n = r^n$ for all $n \geq 0.$ This geometric series is absolutely convergent whenever $\vert r \vert < 1$ and the series is uniformly convergent on any compact subinterval of $(-1, 1).$ Thus, our series is $S(r) = \sum_{n \geq 0} r^n.$ Since this series is uniformly convergent, the derivative of $S$ is the sum of the derivatives of its terms (as functions of $r$). We have that $$\frac{d S}{d r} = \sum_{n \geq 1} n r^{n - 1} = \frac{1}{r} \sum_{n \geq 1} n r^n$$ whenever $r \neq 0$ and of course $\sum_{n \geq 1} n r^n = 0$ if $r = 0.$ Then $\sum_{n \geq 1} n r^n = r \frac{d S}{d r}$ for all $\vert r \vert < 1.$ At the same time, the sum of the geometric series is simply $S(r) = \frac{1}{1 - r},$ so $r \frac{d S}{d r} = \frac{r}{(1 - r)^2} = (1 - \frac{1}{S(r)})(S(r))^2$ whenever $r \neq 0$ or $\frac{d S}{d r} = S(r)(S(r) - 1)$ (this holds for all $\vert r \vert < 1$). Then $\sum_{n \geq 1} n r^n = S(r) (S(r) - 1) = S(r) (S(r) - 1)$. In our case $S(r) = 1521,$ so $\ln \sum_{n \geq 1} n r^n = \ln S(r)(S(r) - 1) = \ln (1520 \cdot 1521)$ I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

If $ |x|<1$ ,

$$f(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+...=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

and

$$f'(x)=1+2x+3x^2+...=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

$$xf'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^n$$

$$=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n$$

thus

$$\ln(\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n)=\ln(x)+2\ln(\frac{1}{1-x})$$

with $\frac{1}{1-x}=1521$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n = c\cdot r^n$ be the $n^{th}$ term of the sequence. $a_0 = 1 \implies c = 1\implies a_n =r^n\implies \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n= 1521\implies \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n = 1521\implies |r| < 1\implies  \dfrac{1}{1-r} = 1521\implies r = 1-\dfrac{1}{1521}= \dfrac{1520}{1521}\implies \ln(\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n)=\ln(\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty nr^n)= \ln(r\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty nr^{n-1})= \ln r+ \ln(\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty nr^{n-1})= \ln r+\ln(\frac{d}{dr}(r+r^2+r^3+\cdots ))=\ln r+\ln\left(\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{r}{1-r}\right)\right)=\ln r+\ln\left(\frac{1}{(1-r)^2}\right)= \ln\left(\frac{r}{(1-r)^2}\right)=\ln\left(r\cdot \frac{1}{(1-r)^2}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{1520}{1521}\cdot 1521^2\right)=\ln (1520\cdot 1521) \approx 14.65$.